# Firefox plugin with google signin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, google-signin

I'm developing a Firefox plugin and trying to add Google Signin feature to the plugin. ( I successfully added this feature to a Chrome plugin before).
I followed the instructions in this article ( https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners). But the signin popup is not showing and no user object is creating, following is my code

```js
var googlePlusUserLoader = (function() {

    var login_btn ;
    var login_dev ;
    var main_dev ;
    var uname_lbl;
    var logout_btn;

    var auth2;
    var googleUser;

    function showLoginScreen(){
        login_dev.style.display = 'block';
        main_dev.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function showMainScreen(){
        login_dev.style.display = 'none';
        main_dev.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideAll(){
        login_dev.style.display = 'none';
        main_dev.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function populateUserInfo(user_info) {
        uname_lbl.innerHTML = user_info.displayName;
    }

    function refreshValues(){
        if (auth2){
            console.log('Refreshing values...');
            googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
        }

    }

    function initAuthObject(){
        gapi.load('auth2',function(){
          auth2 =   gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive profile email',
                cookie_policy: 'none'
            });

            auth2.isSignedIn.listen(function () {
                console.log('signin states changed');
            });

            auth2.currentUser.listen(function(){
                console.log('user changed');
            });

            auth2.signIn().then(function(user) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
            });

        });

    }

    return {
        onload: function () {

            login_btn = document.getElementById('signinBtn');
            login_dev = document.getElementById('divLogin');
            main_dev = document.getElementById('divMain');
            uname_lbl = document.getElementById('username');
            logout_btn = document.getElementById('logoutBtn');

            showLoginScreen();
            initAuthObject();
        }
    };

})();

window.onload = googlePlusUserLoader.onload;
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(user));

this line doesn't log anything in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of complicated stuff.

You simply need to open a tab to this url:

```
gBrowser.loadOneTab('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + jQLike.serialize({
        client_id: 'your client id',
        redirect_uri: 'your redir uri',
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'].join(' '),
        response_type: 'token'
    })
)

// rev1 - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6c172e77fe48f78521f2
var jQLike = { // my stand alone jquery like functions
    serialize: function(aSerializeObject) {
        var serializedStrArr = [];
        for (var cSerializeKey in aSerializeObject) {
            serializedStrArr.push(encodeURIComponent(cSerializeKey) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(aSerializeObject[cSerializeKey]));
        }
        return serializedStrArr.join('&');
    }
};
```

Then just use a `page-mod` on your redirect URI - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

Comment: My pleasure @DilanTharaka - what addon are you making by the way?

Comment: the addon is part for my university project on data mining. Purpose of the addon is to allow users to send their interested web content to our server.