# How to create oAuth project on google developer console for firefox extension

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, firefox-addon

I found that we need to select installed app as application type and redirect_uri would be "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".
But can't see "installed app" as a option in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

HEre is a complete working demo of oauth on twitter - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36490245/1828637

Here is how to do google oauth exactly - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935662/1828637 - just stick it into the twitter oauth example above